# Makefile: command line argument -e of echo is passed to the file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In Makefile, when I write to file using `echo -e "text" >`, -e is also passed:

```
APIM_5 = echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nName=$(MAIN)\nExec=$(MAIN)\nIcon=$(MAIN)\nType=Application\nVersion=1.0\nCategories=Utility;" > AppDir/usr/share/applications/$(MAIN).desktop;
```

But the file I echo into (`$(MAIN).desktop`) looks like below:

```
-e [Desktop Entry]
Name=main
Exec=main
Icon=main
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Categories=Utility;
```

All definitions together and how I call them:

```
APIM_1 = cd output;
APIM_2 = $(RM) AppDir appimage-build;
APIM_3 = mkdir -p AppDir/usr/bin AppDir/usr/share/applications AppDir/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ AppDir/usr/lib;
APIM_4 = touch AppDir/usr/share/applications/$(MAIN).desktop;
APIM_5 = echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nName=$(MAIN)\nExec=$(MAIN)\nIcon=$(MAIN)\nType=Application\nVersion=1.0\nCategories=Utility;" > AppDir/usr/share/applications/$(MAIN).desktop;
APIM_6 = cp $(MAIN) AppDir/usr/bin/;
APIM_7 = cp ../meta/icon/$(MAIN).png AppDir/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/;
APIM_8 = appimage-builder --skip-test;
```

```
appimage: all
    $(APIM_1) $(APIM_2) $(APIM_3) $(APIM_4) $(APIM_5) $(APIM_6) $(APIM_7) $(APIM_8)
    @echo Executing 'appimage' complete!
```

What causes this?

Comment: Make defaults to `sh` as the shell. Seems its echo doesn't support `-e`.

Comment: Wow I cannot thank you enough! `SHELL = bash` was enough. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: The portable way to write this is to use `printf` not `echo`.  The POSIX standard definition of `echo` basically says that any option or handling of non-ASCII text is platform dependent so you cannot use `echo` if you want to output anything other than a simple string.

Comment: @MadScientist that's correct. Thank you too, I will switch to `printf`.